# how to improve the display for a large form in this situation?

Tags: javascript, dom

I made a large form, which has many elements. I use javascript(jquery) to make this form have a step-by-step effect. The problem is that, when the page is loading and before the javascript behavior is triggered, the form shows in a mess and all of its element are shown. Any ideas of improving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common term for this behavior is "flash of unstyled content" (which will be useful when searching for solutions). Technically your content *has* been styled (assuming the page is structured and parsed correctly), but your JavaScript is applying additional style rules and it doesn't do that until the page is loaded.

One technique I regularly use is to set elements to `display:none` until I am ready to work with them. This isn't always practical, as sometimes the element must be visible and/or have a display box for a particular piece of code to work.

See [this article](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/10/1-way-to-avoid-the-flash-of-unstyled-content) for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Group all the form elements in a hidden div (style would be display:none) and have a "loading" message show.

When the document has finished loading, trigger some kind of "startup" function using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //unhide the form here
})
```